# React-dnd - Not sure how to get drag and drop to fire for nested components of the same type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-lists

I'm trying to build a react nested list component that is fully draggable with react-dnd. I have a menu component which contains item components, and each item can also contain other item components. Unfortunately I don't know how to make a node with children draggable or any of its children nodes. Right now I have gotten nodes without childrendraggable, which is a good start, but then fails with:

*TypeError: node is undefined*

any time I try to drag any children. I used the react-dnd [simple sortable](https://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-sortable-simple.html) example as a reference, but that doesn't contain any nesting.

Here is what I have so far:

**Menu.js**

```js
//React DnD
var DragDropContext = require('react-dnd').DragDropContext;
var HTML5Backend = require('react-dnd-html5-backend');

//Item
var Item = require('./item');

var Menu = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            currentNode: this.props.data,
            items: [],
        };
    },
    _clicked(child) {
        this.setState({
            currentNode: child,
        });
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        this._updateData();
    },
   _updateData: function(list) {
        var $this = this;

        if(_.isUndefined(list)){
            var children = $this.props.data.children;
        }
        else{
            if(_.isEmpty(list.children)){
                var children = null;
            }
            else{
                var children = list.children;
            }
        }

        if(children != null){
            var items = children.map(function(item, i) {
                return (<Item
                    key={item.id}
                    id={item.id}
                    child={item}
                    showChildren={this.props.showFirstChildren}
                    clickable={true}
                    onClick={$this._updateData}
                    swapItems={this.swapItems}
                />);
            }.bind(this));

            
            if(!_.isUndefined(list)){
                $this.setState({
                    currentNode: list,
                });
            }
            
            $this.setState({ 
                items: items,
            });
            
        }
    },
    compareItems: function(item1, item2){
        return item1.position - item2.position;
    },
    swapItems: function(id1, id2) {
        var $this = this;

        var items = this.state.currentNode.children;
        var item1 = items.filter(function(i){return i.id === id1})[0];
        var item2 = items.filter(function(i){return i.id === id2})[0];

        var item1Pos = item1.position;
        item1.position = item2.position;
        item2.position = item1Pos;

        items.sort(this.compareItems);

        var newItems = items.map(function(item, i) {
            return (<Item
                key={item.id}
                id={item.id}
                child={item}
                showChildren={this.props.showFirstChildren}
                clickable={true}
                onClick={$this._updateData}
                swapItems={this.swapItems}
            />);
        }.bind(this));

        this.setState({
            items: newItems,
        });
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.currentNode.name}
                <ul>
                    {this.state.items}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    },
});

module.exports = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Menu);
```

**Item.js**

```js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDnD = require('react-dnd');

var ItemTypes = {
  ITEM: 'item'
};

var itemSource = {
  beginDrag: function (props) {
    return {
        id: props.id,
    };
  }
};

var itemTarget = {
    hover: function(props, monitor) {
        var draggedId = monitor.getItem().id;
        if (draggedId !== props.id) {
            props.swapItems(draggedId, props.id);
        }
    }
};

var Item = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        connectDropTarget: React.PropTypes.func,
        connectDragSource: React.PropTypes.func,
        isDragging: React.PropTypes.bool,
        id: React.PropTypes.any,
        swapItems: React.PropTypes.func,
    },
    _clicked(child) {
        this.props.onClick(child);
    },
    render() {
        var $this = this;

        var connectDragSource = $this.props.connectDragSource;
        var isDragging = $this.props.isDragging;
        var connectDropTarget = $this.props.connectDropTarget;
        var child = this.props.child;


        var childrenWrapper = null;
        if (child.children && this.props.showChildren) {
            var children = child.children.map(function(item, i) {
                return (<Item
                    key={item.id}
                    id={item.id}
                    showChildren={false}
                    child={item}
                    onClick={$this._clicked}
                    clickable={true}

                    //passing these items along because otherwise it throws errors
                    connectDropTarget={$this.props.connectDropTarget}
                    connectDragSource={$this.props.connectDragSource}
                    swapItems={$this.props.swapItems}
                />);
            });

            childrenWrapper = (
                <ul>
                    {children}
                </ul>
            );
        }

        var style = {
            cursor: 'move',
            opacity: this.props.isDragging ? 0 : 1
        };

        if (child.children && this.props.clickable) {

            return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(
                 <li style={style} key={child.id} ><a onClick={$this._clicked.bind(null, child)}>{child.title}</a>{childrenWrapper}</li>
            ));
        } else {

            return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(
                 <li style={style} key={child.id}><a>{child.title}{childrenWrapper}</a></li>
            ));
        }
    },
});


var DragSourceDecorator = ReactDnD.DragSource(ItemTypes.ITEM, itemSource,
    function(connect, monitor) {
        return {
            connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
            isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
        };
});

var DropTargetDecorator = ReactDnD.DropTarget(ItemTypes.ITEM, itemTarget,
    function(connect, monitor) {
        return {
            connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
        };
});

module.exports = DropTargetDecorator(DragSourceDecorator(Item));
```

It seems as though the nested items are not being passed dragSource and dropTarget correctly because they are not wrapped when I look at the structure in my React DevTools browser extension, but I'm not sure because I feel react-dnd should take care of that. Thanks in advance, any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shameless plug, but I made [react-sortable-tree](https://github.com/fritz-c/react-sortable-tree) using react-dnd for this very use case.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to pass “connectDropTarget” and “connectDropTarget” to the nested Items. Instead, you have to wrap - inside Item`s render method instead of

```
   return (<Item
           key={item.id}...
```

write

```
   return (<WrappedItem
          key={item.id}…
```

instead of

```
   module.exports = DropTargetDecorator(DragSourceDecorator(Item));
```

write

```
   var WrappedItem = DropTargetDecorator(DragSourceDecorator(Item));
   module.exports = WrappedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem when I try to manipulate tree before drag end. I.e. change leafs order before dragEnd() throw me the same error. But [plain list](https://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-sortable-simple.html) works perfectly.
I stop to change tree during DnD (our designer said - it is not good UX:  jumping to mouse pointer subtree).
So my solution: during DnD just change classes for target and source sub-trees (but do not change leafs order), like:

```
  .source-dnd {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }

  .target-dnd-add {
    border: 1px dotted #aaa;
  }

  .target-dnd-after {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
  }

  .target-dnd-before {
    border-top: 1px dotted #aaa;
  }
```

Also don't forget about [`monitor.isOver({ shallow: true })`](http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drop-target.html)